# Pushing values to already existing column of array type in laravel

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, laravel

I am trying to push values to already existing column of array type in laravel but instead it replaces the already existing values in the column when I update

My code

```
public function mergeSkillToArtisan(Request $request){

        $identity = $request->post("identity");
        $ids = json_encode($request->post("skillAssessment"));
        if(SkillAssessmentMerging::where("user_id", $identity)->count() > 0){
            SkillAssessmentMerging::whereIn('user_id', $identity)->update(["skill_assessment_ids" => $ids // This is where the problem is]);
        }else{
            SkillAssessmentMerging::create([
                'user_id' => $identity,
                'skill_assessment_ids' => $ids
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ->update() you are replacing column values. That is how it works.
To do what you want you should first select existing data, merge it with new ids, filter unique values and then update column.

```
public function mergeSkillToArtisan(Request $request)
{
    $identity = $request->post("identity");
    $ids = json_encode($request->post("skillAssessment"));
    $existingRecord = SkillAssessmentMerging::where(
        "user_id",
        $identity
    )->first();
    if ($existingRecord) {
        $ids = array_unique(
            array_merge($ids, $existingRecord->skill_assessment_ids)
        );
        $existingRecord->update(["skill_assessment_ids" => $ids]);
        return;
    }
    SkillAssessmentMerging::create([
        "user_id" => $identity,
        "skill_assessment_ids" => $ids,
    ]);
}
```

From what I can see you are trying to assign some kind of relation to user. Maybe will be better to consider using ManyToMany relationship. Then you will be able to use methods like `$user->assesmentSkills->syncWithoutDetaching($ids)`

Answer (score 0):

To add the new values to the existing ones, you can use a special method called `DB::raw()` to combine the new values with the old ones.
You can update your code like this

```
public function mergeSkillToArtisan(Request $request){
$identity = $request->post("identity");
$ids = json_encode($request->post("skillAssessment"));

if(SkillAssessmentMerging::where("user_id", $identity)->count() > 0){
    SkillAssessmentMerging::whereIn('user_id', $identity)->update([
        "skill_assessment_ids" => DB::raw("CONCAT(skill_assessment_ids, '," . $ids . "')")
    ]);
}else{
    SkillAssessmentMerging::create([
        'user_id' => $identity,
        'skill_assessment_ids' => $ids
    ]);
}
}
```

In this updated version, the `DB::raw()` method is used to concatenate the old values in the `skill_assessment_ids` column with the new values passed in `$ids`. The `CONCAT()` function is used to concatenate the old values with a comma separator and the new values.